# Java thread using different CLI window

Tags: java, multithreading, command-line-interface

I am using a separate thread in my class to get user interaction via CLI. However, I would like to have this interaction in another CLI window but I can't seem a way to achieve this. Is this possible? and how can one achieve this?.

code of my class:

```
private void userInteraction(){
    System.out.println("(client)starting user interaction");
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        // create a scanner so we can read the command-line input
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                //  prompt for the user's name
                System.out.print("Enter the desired operation: ");
                // get their input as a String
                String operation = scanner.next();

                switch(operation.toLowerCase()) {
                    case "publish":
                        System.out.print("(client) asking for publish: ");
                        // code block
                        break;
                    case "subscribe":
                        System.out.print("(client) asking for subscribe: ");
                        System.out.print("Enter the desired htag to subscribe on: ");
                        String htag = scanner.next();
                        if(Character.compare(htag.charAt(0) ,'#') ==0){
                            System.out.print("Er is een htag: ");
                            subscribe(htag.substring(1));
                        }else{
                            subscribe(htag);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "start":
                        System.out.print("(client) asking for start: ");
                        System.out.print("Enter the desired operation: ");
                        int amount_tweets = scanner.nextInt();
                        System.out.print("Enter the desired operation: ");
                        int seconds = scanner.nextInt();
                        try {
                            start(amount_tweets,seconds);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.print("Unsupported operation: ");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: How would that work? I currently have output and input message in same cli but I want them seperate.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread

Comment: Short answer is "no", long answer is, "it's complicated".  A `Thread` is only going to run within the current "process", so, that would mean in the terminal window you have open.  If you want multiple terminal windows and have them share information, then you need to consider some kind of "inter process communication" workflow, such as using a `Socket` to talk between the processes